# Error trying to test an Angular2 component with an external template

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, jasmine, karma-runner

I've been trying to familiarize myself with unit testing in an Angular2 app and have been following the Angular documentation on testing but have run into an error I haven't been able to figure out.

I have a simple demo app that I have put together to play with the testing. I have it setup and configured exactly like my full project. It is an Angular2 app built on top of ASP.NET Core MVC using the templates and setup provided here (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack). I'm using Webpack and Typescript with Karma and Jasmine for the Unit Testing.

The problem that I am having is that when I try to implement the tests for a component with an external template (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#async-in-before-each) I am getting an error on the async beforeEach function. While all of my tests pass successfully, I am getting an error in my editor and when I run the full application. The error that I am receiving is: `error TS2345: Argument of type '(done: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.`

While my prefered solution would be to fix the error, since my tests are passing, I'd settle for getting things configured so that my .spec.ts files are not included in the bundles Webpack creates for the prod site (note my spec.ts files live side-by-side with the .ts files that implement the components)

banner.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { BannerComponent } from '../banner.component';

describe('BannerComponent (templateUrl)', () => {

    let comp: BannerComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;

    // async beforeEach
    //This is the function that is producing the error
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [BannerComponent], // declare the test component
        })
        .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
    }));

    // synchronous beforeEach
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);

        comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

        // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
        el = de.nativeElement;
    });

    it('no title in the DOM until manually call `detectChanges`', () => {
        expect(el.textContent).toEqual('');
    });

    it('should display original title', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
    });

    it('should display a different test title', () => {
        comp.title = 'Test Title';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(el.textContent).toContain('Test Title');
    });

});
```

karma.conf.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (config) => {
    config.set({
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'],
        files: [
            './node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
            './karma.entry.js'
        ],
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        phantomJsLauncher: {
            exitOnResourceError: true
        },
        preprocessors: {
            'karma.entry.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'growl'],
        singleRun: false,
        webpack: require('./webpack.config.test'),
        webpackMiddleware: {
            noInfo: true
        }
    });
};
```

karma.entry.js

```
require('es6-shim');
require('reflect-metadata');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy'); // since zone.js 0.6.14
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');

const browserTesting = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');
const coreTesting = require('@angular/core/testing');

coreTesting.TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
    browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

const context = require.context('./ClientApp/app/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);

context.keys().forEach(context);

Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 2000;
```

webpack.config.test.js

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { loader: 'raw', test: /\.(css|html)$/ },
            { test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /node_modules/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        root: path.resolve('.', 'ClientApp/app')
    }
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='Watch - Development' />
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var allFilenamesExceptJavaScript = /\.(?!js(\?|$))([^.]+(\?|$))/;

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
var sharedConfig = {
    resolve: { extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string!css' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } }
        ]
    }
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
var clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist') },
    devtool: isDevBuild ? 'inline-source-map' : null,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

// Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
var serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: [allFilenamesExceptJavaScript] })] // Don't bundle .js files from node_modules
});

module.exports = [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
```

Comment: You aren't performing any asynchronous work in the callback so why bother to use async(...)?

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's async because the component under test has an external template. Since reading that file is needed to create the component and it is an asnyc operation, the test setup needs to be async so that the external template file is read before it tries to create an instance of the component. You can read more about that in the Angular documentation at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-external-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've figured out my issue. When setting the project up I apparently installed an old version of `'@types/jasmine'` which apparently has a different method signature for `beforeEach()` that could not accept the done:any returned by the `async()` function. I updated the `'@types/jasmine'` file to the latest version, which supports that version of the `beforeEach()` all of my errors went away.